Apply a command using PowerShell to all folders with a specific name
Dropbox's support shows that you can use the following command to have Dropbox ignore a specific file or folder:
Set-Content -Path 'C:\Users\yourname\Dropbox\YourFileName.pdf' -Stream com.dropbox.ignored -Value 1
Is there a way I can use PowerShell to set this value on all folders named FileContentIndex on my hard drive?
Thanks!

You can use Get-ChildItem to list directories then you can pipe that output directly to Set-Content.

-Recurse is used for a recursive search.
-Directory is used to list only directories.
-Filter is used to list only folders with name FileContentIndex.
Use -Force if you also need to include Hidden folders.

$startingPath = 'path\to\theParentDir'
Get-ChildItem $startingPath -Recurse -Directory -Filter FileContentIndex |
    Set-Content -Stream com.dropbox.ignored -Value 1

